# Validar usuario con consulta linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy realizando un login , por el cual debo validar si el campo usuario y contraseña que fueron ingresador en el formulario de login existen dentro de la base de datos, estoy realizando una consulta linq dentro del metodo login por el cual deseo pasar los paramento a las variables que declare dentro del metodo osea user y contra.

Mi problema es que no terminar de validar los valores por el cual siempre deja ingresar a cualquier texto que se escriba entra directamente al formulario menuprincipal. No se si esta sea la forma correcta de realizar este procedimiento.

ESTO ES LA CLASE USUARIO_L EN EL CAPA LOGICA

```
public bool Login(string user, string contra)
    {
        using (programacion_ii_c db = new programacion_ii_c())
        {
            try
            {
                var qw = from u in db.Usuarios
                         join x in db.Roles
                         on u.IdUsuario equals x.IdRol
                         where u.Usuario == user && u.Contrasena == contra
                         select new
                         {
                             Nombres = u.Nombres,
                             Usuario = u.Usuario,
                             IdUsuario = u.IdUsuario,
                             IdRol = x.IdRol,
                             Rol = x.Nombre,
                             Codigo = x.Codigo
                         };

               return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
                throw ex;

            }
        }
    }
```

ESTO ES EN LA CAPA PRESENTACION DEL FORMULARIO LOGIN EN EL BOTON ACCEDER

```
private void BtnAcceder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtUsuario.Text != "Usuario")
        {
            if (TxtContraseÒa.Text != "Contrasena")
            {

                Usuario_E usuario = new Usuario_E();                
                Usuario_L acceso = new Usuario_L();
                var validacion = acceso.Login(TxtUsuario.Text, TxtContraseÒa.Text);
                if (validacion == true)
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de contrasena", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Por que siempre devuelves un **`true`**, por eso siempre dejara pasar cualquier texto ingresado. una opcion seria hacer un `FirstOrDefault` y validar si el valor devuelto es nulo o no.

Comment: debes validar que tu variable qw no sea nula o este en blanco para retornar el true

Comment: Ya realize la validacion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código siempre hace la consulta, pero no hay ningún momento donde valides que, si lo que trae la consulta es lo que necesitas. Tal como lo tienes ahora, hace la consulta, y podría no devolverte valores, pero como se hace la consulta sin errores, el código continua y te devuelve `true`. puedes agregar un `if` que revise si tu consulta devolvió algún registro, si lo hizo, devuelve `true`, si no, devuelve `false`.

```
public bool Login(string user, string contra)
    {
        using (programacion_ii_c db = new programacion_ii_c())
        {
            try
            {
                var qw = from u in db.Usuarios
                         join x in db.Roles
                         on u.IdUsuario equals x.IdRol
                         where u.Usuario == user && u.Contrasena == contra
                         select new
                         {
                             Nombres = u.Nombres,
                             Usuario = u.Usuario,
                             IdUsuario = u.IdUsuario,
                             IdRol = x.IdRol,
                             Rol = x.Nombre,
                             Codigo = x.Codigo
                         };
               //si tiene al menos un valor, devuelve true, caso contrario devuelve false
               if(qw.ToList().Count>0){
                   return true;
               }else{
                   return false;
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
                throw ex;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sabia que me hacia falta una condición pero no sabia como plasmarla muchas gracias

Comment: un placer poder ayudar :)